# Getting a Weighted Average Date Value?

Tags: c#, datetime, average

If I have 50% weight on 6/3/2011 and 50% weight on 6/1/2011, the weighted average will be 6/2/2011.

Now, I can't seem to figure out how I can do this with uneven weights, since it's not like you can multiply a DateTime by a double, and sum up the results (or can you?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dateA = ...;
DateTime dateB = ...;
TimeSpan difference = dateA - dateB;
double units = difference.Ticks;
// Do your weighted logic here on 'units'.
DateTime average = dateA + new TimeSpan(units);
```

Something like the above (you get the idea - basically need to normalise the difference into a format you can work with, i.e. ticks, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference between two dates(start and end) in terms of days. Apply the weight on the `difference_days` and get the final output date by `startdate + weightedDays`

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply a datetime by a double, but you can set a value for date1 and date2 on a scale (1 to 100) and figure out where the value you would be in the middle. The 1 versus 100 ends up on 50 in your 50/50 scenario.

You then have to figure the number of days in the range. You can then multiply by the weighted decimal (as a percent) and turn that into number of days. Then add that number of days to the first value.

Since you can turn dates into numbers, this gives some pretty interesting other means of accomplishing this. A TimeSpan is one way of setting this up as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the long timestamps of the DateTime Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `Ticks` property of `DateTime`?  Something like:

```
        DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2011, 6, 5);
        DateTime secondDate = new DateTime(2011, 6, 1);
        double weight1 = 0.4;
        double weight2 = 0.6;

        var averageTicks = (firstDate.Ticks * weight1) + (secondDate.Ticks * weight2) / 2;

        DateTime averageDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(averageTicks));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the weighted average formula would be sumproduct `(Weights*Dates)/sum` (Weights)

Where sumproduct means the sum of all factors. Factors being the multiplication of weights and date.ticks. If sum of weights=1 then only the numerator remains.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, only with money(cashflows) which means there is a compounding\discounting rate of growth\decay of value known as time value of money)...

In order to enable you to avoid that mistake i composed a spreadsheet found at:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqGuYeJW3VHggc9ARWCxcHIeodd2Pg

You just have to experiment with it!!!...And understand that at 0% interest rate the results are identical to the weighted average described in other posts but as rate increases there is deviation. Then you gotta build an XNPV function for your programming language and fuse it with your app.

also there are a number of examples with growth in algebra books.maybe there is an intersection with them and datetime-offsets found in cashflows